# How to convert string[] to NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#

I want to change the `allKeys` to a NameValueCollection type. When i do `allKeys[2]` I get back a value that is saved from the key.

```
var appSettingsSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
var allKeys = appSettingsSection.Settings.AllKeys;
```

I want to access the values by doing `allKeys[key]` and the value will be given, Not `allKeys[2]`

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with just doing

```
var element = appSettingsSection.Settings["key"];
```

as the indexer takes a `string`?

Answer (score 0):

It already is a NameValueCollection,

use

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
```

Instead.